# Best approach to maintain many dump for a single structure

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have many database equal to each other with differences only in the data. I want to maintain a dump for each database for use in a installation process.

is recommended maintain it as a single file or split into many files?

Answer (score 0):

Always the best practice is to take each database's backup with a separate file.

## Why?

1. You can restore any database to anywhere.
2. It'll help to refresh you Dev database.
3. It'll help in PITR.
4. You can restore any specific table from the specific database backup.
5. Finally it will save a lot of time while restoring a single Database.

## Recomendation:

Keep you database backup in multiple locations. This will help you in case of any disaster.

1. SAN
2. NFS
3. S3
4. Or any other location apart from the Database server.

Answer (score 0):

If they are really equal in their structure, I would keep one definition file only.

But, because you added the 'backup' tag, I have to mention that you should keep a separate backup of each database, to be sure there is no potential for a huge data loss.  Also, test the 'restorability' regularly - a backup that cannot be restored is just as bad as no backup.

### But there is a better idea

I think you have your application code under version control, with a well-defined deployment process in place.  The good news is that you can do that easily with databases, too.  Keep the table definitions in their separate files - one file for a table, its indexes and other closely related objects.  If you happen to have other type of objects, keep them similarly in their own files.  Then have a directory per schema, store the aforementioned files nicely put under those.  Name your files so that you can do something like

```
find . -name *sql | sort -V | xargs cat | psql {to your database}
```

For example:

```
my_database
|____10_schema1
     |____04_tables
          |____10_table1.sql
          |____20_table2.sql
```

When choosing the numbers, tables that depend on others come later than the dependency.

The last step is to have some mechanism in place that can roll out structure changes - you can roll your own DB diffs, use Flyway or otherwise.  Keep the base files in sync, so that you can always recreate the latest structure from them, without messing with the diffs.